# codename tree component , collapse method null pointer exception

Tags: codenameone

how to use the CollapsePath in Tree Component codename one

using Tree component using the collapsePath cause null pointer exception due to container = this .... how to solve this issue ..
i am specified the arguments as string obj of parent, child, child
can you specify the  how to use collapsePath and expandPath
i have tried using both the expandPath and collapsePath but both causing the same problem

Tree dt = new Tree(new StringArrayTreeModel());
dt.collapsePath("Colors","Red","df","gf");

Comment: What's the stack of the exception? 
Is the path expanded?

Comment: Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.codename1.ui.tree.Tree.collapsePathNode(Tree.java:327)
 at com.codename1.ui.tree.Tree.collapsePath(Tree.java:377)
 at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication$6.actionPerformed(MyApplication.java:161

Comment: ya the tree has been expanded.. i hava tried to the expandPath but that throw the null pointer exception ..........

Comment: Form hi = new Form("Welcome",BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER_ABSOLUTE)  Tree tree = new  Tree();
        tree.expandPath("Colors","Red");
        hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER,tree);
        hi.show(); this too cause the null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing for this case would be:

```
    Form current = new Form("Tree Test", new BorderLayout());
    Tree t = new Tree();

    current.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, t);
    current.addShowListener(e -> t.expandPath(null, "Colors"));
    current.show();
```

However, there is a bug in the current version related to the null root argument which should be fixed in the coming update next Friday (12th May 2017).

Comment: is there is any method to add leaf to the tree dynamically

Comment: Sure, implement the `TreeModel` interface

Comment: i have implemented the tree model and  add the children dynamically but the tree doesn't reflect the changes , once a collapse the tree then the changes visible ....only when getchildren() method called the tree gets updated ...

Comment: You need to fire events reflecting the change from the model